# Navigate among <em> elements in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a container div in a page, how can I give focus to a certain  elements?

I've tried the following:

```
<div id="modalTextDocument" style="height:15px;overflow:scroll;">
<em>Hello</em>
... various text...
<em>other highlighted element<em> you can see this only scrolling...
etc...
</div>
```

This jQuery code is not working:

```
$('div#modalTextDocument').find('em')[1].focus();
```

Comment: `em` elements can’t receive focus per default - you have to first of all “enable” that via the `tabindex` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution would be adding `tabindex` for each element that you want to target by `focus` which is not focusable by default.

By specifying tabindex, you are basically telling browser the order in which elements should be getting focus, moreover you can set tabindex for any element, not just those that are able to receive focus by default.

```js
$('div#modalTextDocument').find('em')[1].focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalTextDocument">
  <em tabindex="1">Hello</em>
  ... various text...
  <em tabindex="2">other highlighted element</em> you can see this only scrolling...
  etc...
</div>
```

Now you can focus both `other highlighted element` and `Hello` by either hitting `tab` or clicking on them (or you can also set focus on them programatically as with the code above).